# Elegant way of checking if a value is within a range and setting it's value if it falls outside of the range?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

What I want to do is quite simple in itself, but I'm wondering is there is some really neat and compact way of accomplishing the same thing.

I have a float variable, and I want to check if it's value is between 0 and 1. If it's smaller than 0 I want to set it to zero, if it's larger than 1 I want to set it to 1.

Usually I do this:

```
// var myVar is set before by some calculation

if(myVar > 1){
    myVar = 1;
}
if(myVar < 0){ 
    myVar = 0;
}
```

Does anyone know of a more elegant/compact way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the Min/Max solution is very succinct, it's far from obvious what is going on.

I would opt for a function that does just what you have:

```
myVar = constrainToRange(myVar, 0, 1);

function constrainToRange(x, min, max) {
    if (x < min) {
        x = min;
    }
    else if( x > max) {
        x = max;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: +1 Hard to beat the clarity of this solution. And I was just about to suggest "constrain", but you beat me to it. :) You could even add this to `Number.prototype` as an option.

Comment: so much code.... `Number.prototype.constrain=function(x,min,max) {if (x<min)return min;if (x>max)return max;return x;}`

Comment: I've chosen this one, combined with user1689607's suggestion this offers a really clear and clean solution to my problem.

Comment: @mplungjan If you were to write that out across multiple lines, you'd have the exact same amount of code, since I *always* use braces. If Jeroen prefers a different style he's welcome to adapt it.

Comment: I left out else and brackets :)

Comment: Correct prototyped version would look more like this: `Number.prototype.constrain=function(min,max) {if (this<min)return min;if (this>max)return max;return +this;}`

Answer (score 8):

One possible solution:

```
myVar = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, myVar));
```

Another:

```
myVar = myVar < 0 ? 0 : myVar > 1 ? 1 : myVar;
```

Comment: If you use ternary, at least bracket the else condition - multiple ternaries in one line get VERY confusing, very quickly

Comment: The Math.min Math.max solution is nice, I'll be using that I think! I'll accept in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Use Math.min and Math.max, and avoid having a condition.

```
var MAX = 100;
var MIN = 50;

var val = 75;
console.log( Math.max(MIN, Math.min(MAX, val)) );

var val = 49;
console.log( Math.max(MIN, Math.min(MAX, val)) );

var val = 101;
console.log( Math.max(MIN, Math.min(MAX, val)) );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an option which can be expanded very easily to test more than simple min/max:

```
myVar = parseFloat( (myVar < 0 && '0') || (myVar > 1 && 1) || myVar );
```

The `parseFloat` and returning 0 as a string are important, otherwise it drops through that condition when it should stop there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
 myVal = myVal >= 1 ? 1 : Math.min(Math.abs(myVal), 0)
```